# movie-trailer; not defined `movieTrailer`

Tags: reactjs, video, referenceerror

I am using a react app and trying to use `movieTrailer(..)` from `movie-trailer`.
The thing is error is keeping saying `movieTrailer(movie.name || "")`is never defined. I did import `import movieTrailer from 'movie-trailer';` and in  '/Users/kevinsong/Desktop/netflix-clone/node_modules/movie-trailer/index.js' there is function called `movieTrailer`

```
async function movieTrailer( movie, options, cb, legacy ) {

        /* Fetch movie trailers */

        // Massage inputs
        let config = {
            multi: false,
            id: false,
            year: null,
            language: null,

            // Public Key on purpose
            apiKey: '9d2bff12ed955c7f1f74b83187f188ae'
        }

        if ( !options ) {

            options = {}

        }

        if ( typeof movie !== 'string' && !options.tmdbId ) {

            throw Error( 'Expected first parameter to be a movie or TMDB ID (string)' )

        } else if ( typeof options === 'function' ) {

            // Second parameter is the callback
            cb = options
            options = null

        } else if ( typeof options === 'boolean' || options === 'true' ) {

            // Second parameter is multi
            config.multi = options

        } else if ( typeof options === 'string' || typeof options === 'number' ) {

            // Second parameter is year
            config.year = options

            /* BACKWARDS-COMPATABILITY FOR v1 */
            if ( typeof legacy === 'function' && ( typeof cb === 'boolean' || ( typeof cb === 'string' && cb === 'true' ) ) ) {

                // Third parameter is multi
                config.multi = cb
                cb = legacy

            }
            /* END BACKWARDS-COMPATABILITY */

        } else if ( typeof options === 'object' ) {

            // Set options
            config = Object.assign( config, options )

        }

        // Remove invalid callback
        if ( typeof cb !== 'function' ) {

            cb = null

        }

        const movieId = config.tmdbId ? config.tmdbId : ( await getMovieId( movie, config )
            .catch( error => {

                handleErrors(error)
                return null

            } ) )

        // Get the TMDB content ID
        if ( !movieId ) {

            // Failed
            return null

        }

        // Get the trailers themselves
        const result = getTrailer( movieId, config )

        if ( !result ) {

            // Failed
            return null

        }

        // Call callback if supplied
        if ( cb ) {

            return result
                .then( response => cb( null, response ) )
                .catch( error => cb( error, null ) )

        }

        // return promise
        return result

    }

    // Exposed public method
    return movieTrailer

}
```

Please help out why I am getting undefined `movieTrailer` reference error.

Comment: Is the function exported?

Comment: all I did was `npm i -g movie-trailer`. Do I need to modifies the `"/Users/kevinsong/Desktop/netflix-clone/node_modules/movie-trailer/index"`?

Comment: I wouldn't in general recommend to modify files in `node_modules` as you're going to lose your changes if you update.

Comment: I wasn't able to get version 2.0.7+ to work, but 2.0.6 does work for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-feather-uny2l?file=/src/App.js.

Comment: what version are you talking about here? I mean version of what

Comment: The version of the `movie-trailer` library. Look at the sandbox and the dependencies.

Comment: Thank you about that. I put `"movie-trailer": "2.0.6",` in package.json and ```"movie-trailer": {
      "version": "2.0.6",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/movie-trailer/-/movie-trailer-2.0.6.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-altBMwwPQR1y+AVX5b5TPBiQQuR2vSzDdK6hyy4cQkMRt5oDodn9+Hz/YF9H79nYqQlfU6oXxQkp67WdjmPUtA==",
      "requires": {
        "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
        "meow": "^4.0.0",
        "node-fetch": "^2.1.2",
        "np": "^7.2.0",
        "xo": "^0.37.1"
      },``` in package-lock.json, but still the same issue..